# Adding htmlhelp to project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying, without much luck, to add chm options to an existing project.

`Main.cpp` has this:

```
#include "HtmlHelp.h"

int OpenHelp(LPTSTR arg1)
{
  HWND _Hhdl = HtmlHelp(GetDesktopWindow(), arg1, HH_DISPLAY_TOPIC, NULL);
  return 1;
}
```

`htmlhelp.lib` is set in `Linker/Input/additional Dependencies`.

The error I'm getting is:

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _HtmlHelpW@16 referenced in function "int __cdecl OpenHelp(wchar_t *)" (?OpenHelp@@YAHPA_W@Z)
```

I'm new to C++ so I'm assuming my function is at fault somehow.

The idea was the function would be passed a sting in the `"C:\Help.chm\::/Topic.html"` format.

Comment: Works fine.  You, somehow, didn't get the Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies set correctly.  Try `#pragma comment(lib, "htmlhelp.lib")` instead.

Comment: I have now tried that but still get the same errors.